# add a line feed with notepad++ over a long line

Tags: notepad++

I have always wondered how to do that with `notepad++` , so maybe you can enlighten me on this subject as I have encountered this case a few times.

Let's say I have a file with a long line , without a `cr` or a `lf` at the end of the line.

Which make something like this

```
banana pear orange yellow [...] green cherry
```

I would like to put `lf` over every 15 words, a word is separated by a space.

How can I do that with notepad++?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `((?:\S+\s){14}\S+)`
Replace with: `$1\n`

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/01/essential-guide-to-regular-expressions-tools-tutorials-and-resources/

Comment: The reference for PCRE regex is: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt and a good tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/